# Refresh UI with a Timer in WPF (with BackgroundWorker?)

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, backgroundworker

We have an application in WPF that shows data via ObservableCollection. After 5 minutes, I want to refresh the data.

I thought I could use the `System.Timers.Timer` object for its `Elapsed` event and then call a `BackgroundWorker` to call the method that starts the job. The method is on a ViewModel class.

But it seems that there's a problem the threads.

So I tried with the Dispatcher, but same thing again.

Here's my (simplified and not optimized) code :

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationController"/> class.
/// </summary>
public ApplicationController()
{
    CreateDefaultTabs();

    Timer timer = new Timer(20000); //20 secs for testing purpose.
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeBeforeRefreshElapsed);
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimeBeforeRefreshElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { RefreshData(); }));
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { UpdateLayout(); }));
}

private void RefreshData()
{
    foreach (object tab in _tabItems)
    {
        if (tab is TitleDetailsView)
        {
            TitleDetailsViewModel vm = ((TitleDetailsView)tab).DataContext as TitleDetailsViewModel;
            vm.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateLayout()
{
    foreach (object tab in _tabItems)
    {
        if (tab is TitleDetailsView)
        {
            TitleDetailsViewModel vm = ((TitleDetailsView)tab).DataContext as TitleDetailsViewModel;
            vm.HandleGetTitleBySymbolResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: There is a problem [with] the threads? What problem exactly?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Why not use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)? That will "tick" in the dispatcher thread already.

Beyond that, it's hard to say what's wrong just from your description of "there's a problem with the threads".

Comment: Seriously, I need to get your low-hanging-fruit notification algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This answer explains the problem with using the Timer vs DispatcherTimer when updating the UI.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258909/1698182

I have not tried this but for periodic work items that will use a thread do the bulk of the work this looks like it will do the trick.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj248676.aspx