# System.Threading.Timer with WPF/C# problems

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with WPF/C# app and I wrote a method which execute an another method in every 5 seconds.
I used System.Threading namespace to build a function:

```
   prviate void TimerMetod()
    {
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => MyFunction(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
```

Unfortunately MyFunction is called only once, what did i do wrong?

Comment: You should always use a DispatcherTimer in WPF rather than System.Threading.Timer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258830/dispatchertimer-vs-a-regular-timer-in-wpf-app-for-a-task-scheduler

Comment: @Peregrine: _"You should always use a DispatcherTimer in WPF"_ -- that's simply false. In WPF, for on-UI-thread timing, async/await is now "best practice". And it is _not_ correct to state that either that or `DispatcherTimer` must _always_ be used. There are many scenarios where the thread pool-based timers are perfectly appropriate, even in a WPF program.

Comment: But i assume, i should use DispatcherTimer?
Am i right?

Comment: @Xallares When you need to cyclically updated the UI, DispatcherTimer is the right choice. See the edited answer for how you would typically create and start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use local variable for the timer, timer will be disposed after TimerMetod ends, timer must be a class member.

Use DispatcherTimer. For WPF this is better option than System.Threading.Timer

Threading.Timer calls delegate on  non-UI thread unlike DispatcherTimer. This could be issue when you code interacts with UI.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
    private int _count;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };
        _dispatcherTimer.Tick += OnTimer;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnTimer(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        _count++;
        text.Text = "Count:" + _count;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Start Timer" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="text"></TextBlock>
    
</Grid>
```